# How to get list apps installed in device and populate them into adapter using background thread?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain listview and adapter that populate items in listview. Problem is that i have get list of apps installed in device and populate them in listview which is working fine, But problem is that pause screen for some second so i want to do it using background thread. How do i do that

code:-

```
 private List<CWhiteListAppsModel> getInstalledApps() {
    List<CWhiteListAppsModel> res = new ArrayList<CWhiteListAppsModel>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = mContext.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!isSystemPackage(p))) {
            boolean isBlackList = false;
            if (blackListAppsDataSet != null) {
                for (int j = 0; j < blackListAppsDataSet.size(); j++) {
                    CBlackListAppsModel blackListAppsModel = blackListAppsDataSet.get(j);
                    Log.e(TAG, "p*****" + blackListAppsModel.getPackName());
                    if (p.applicationInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(blackListAppsModel.getPackName())) {
                        // This package is whitlist package
                        isBlackList = true;
                    }

                }
            }
            // We don't need to add white list app in the list
            if (isBlackList) {
                continue;
            }
            String appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(mContext.getPackageManager()).toString();
            Drawable icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(mContext.getPackageManager());
            String packageName = p.applicationInfo.packageName;

            Log.e(TAG, "package name::" + packageName);
            Log.e(TAG, "icon name::" + icon);
            res.add(new CWhiteListAppsModel(appName, icon, packageName));
        }
    }
    return res;
}
 List<CWhiteListAppsModel> installedApps = getInstalledApps();
    installedAppAdapter = new CWhiteListAppsAdapter(mContext, installedApps, CWhiteListAppsFragment.this);
    appCount();
    userInstalledApps.setAdapter(installedAppAdapter);
    // Set layout manager to position the items
    userInstalledApps.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
```

Comment: You can use AsyncTask for that.

Comment: How edit some code snap with instructions........